# How to destroy a component when building SPA with Vue.js and vue-router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Say I have a router map looks like this:

```
router.map({
'/a_example': {
    component: A
},

'/b_example': {
    component: B
},
```

There is a Ajax Request every 1 sec on component A. I load `/a_example` in the browser and click the link on the `component A` to go to `/b_example`. Now the browser is showing component B as expected. However, the Ajax Request doesn't stop and still sends request every 1 sec.

My guess is that vue-router still keeps component A under the hood so that it won't hit performance issues.

Anyway all I've found out in http://vuejs.github.io/vue-router/en/view.html is this `keep-alive` thing. But it's deactive by default and I am sure I did't use it.

Is there some kind of options I can make use of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vue-router provides a number of optional [transition hooks](http://vuejs.github.io/vue-router/en/pipeline/hooks.html). You can stop sending ajax requests inside the `deactivate` hook.

```
Vue.component('component-A', {
  route: {
    deactivate: function () {
    //stop sending requests
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

In the latest version of VueRouter (v.2.1.1), you can use an [In-Component Guard](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards):

**beforeRouteLeave**

```
const Foo = {
  template: `...`,
  beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
    // stop your requests here
    // ...
    next()
  }
}
```